# Full calendar revertFunc() not working on eventResize

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar v1.6.1. In my code when event resize I am checking certain conditions and if not valid make it as original by calling `revertFunc()`. But currently I am getting error

> Uncaught TypeError: revertFunc is not a function

But revert function is working on eventDrop and drop events. My code is as follows

```
eventResize: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {
   if(!valid){
       revertFunc(); // Get the error
   }
},
eventDrop: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {
   if(!valid){
       revertFunc(); // Working fine
   }
}
```

Comment: i never seen like `if(not valid)`. I am sure it should be like `if(!valid)`

Comment: It is just text to understand.

Answer (score 0):

In docs of fullcalendar on this [LINK](https://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_ui/eventResize/) (your version), there is revert function fourth parameter. You need to extend eventResize function on four (or more) parameters and set revertFunc on 4th place, like this (from docs):

```
function( event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) { }
```